# What is the difference between a certificate, a signature and a thumbprint in case of windows exe/binaries?

Tags: windows, hash, certificate, exe, signature

I am trying to understand the difference between signature, thumbprint and certificate in the context of windows executable and binaries. I looked up on the internet before posting this question but I did not get a concise differentiation. Maybe my understanding of the 3 terms is not clear in the first place. Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A **certificate** is a document produced usually using X.509 standards which you can use to distribute your public key on the internet and prove to the rest of the world that you are who you claim to be (authentication), that is, if you say you are www.example.com then that is who really are.

A certificate is often signed by a trusted certificate authority (CA), using the CA's private key. The **digital signature** is the part of the certificate which can be used to validate whether the CA really signed the cert. It is generally computed by hashing the first part of the certificate and then using the specified encryption algorithm with the CA private key.

The **thumbprint** is merely a hash (SHA1 or SHA256) over the entire certificate including the signature.

Note that these terms have the same relevance whether you are on Windows or any other platform.